# How do I run .py files through the Anaconda interpreter by double-clicking on them in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm setting up my home computer for basic python development. I've managed to install Anaconda through the command line but I'm not sure how to make .py files run through the Anaconda interpreter when double-clicked.

i.e. I did this on my Windows computer at work by right clicking on a .py file and then choosing open with > open with another application > navigating to {C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3} > clicking on python.exe and then clicking 'open'. Is there an equivalent way of doing this on Linux? I'm running Pop!_OS.

I've tried clicking 'open with' but there was no option to open with another application. I also wouldn't know what type of file I would be looking for whereas I knew in Windows I was looking for a .exe

I've also tried right clicking on a .py file, going on the 'Permissions' tab, checking the box for 'Allow executing file as a program' and going to Files > preferences > Behaviour and changed the Executable Text Files option from 'Display them' to 'Run them'.

Comment: This doesn't depend on python or anaconda, but solely on the window manager / desktop environment you're using.  As such the question is ill-conceived, there's no single **linux** specific way to do this. And as for supporting a bazillion of different desktops ... that's imho no task for SO. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score 1):

The most common way on linux to make things executable is by adding the executable flag to the file. On command line, if your file is called `script.py`:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

It is important that your script starts with a description of how to execute it.

For python, your script should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Also, for clarification, there is no `.exe` file in Linux. The equivalent to that is the previously mentioned executable flag.

Comment: Well, that doesn't actually answers his question, but shows a proper way to execute the scripts on a linux machine.

Comment: Not the answer that he asked for, but the answer he deserved ;) not sure if OP is aware of the subtle differences between Windows and Linux, so I think this is the right way to go

Comment: I agree. OP should also note that linux binaries don't have an "exe" extension.

Comment: Updated the response :)

Comment: I'm aware that .exe doesn't exist on linux hence "whereas I knew in Windows I was looking for a .exe".

I'm trying to find out how to make all .py files run though the Anaconda interpreter when double-clicked.

Comment: I think if you add the executable flag to the file, it should execute it on double click instead of editing it.

Comment: Ok, didn't read the 'all .py-files'. My answer is invalid then. But honestly, I don't think that is the way it should be done, not all py-files are executables, most of them will probably be library files. That's why the executable bit exists in the first place.

Comment: If a .py file is not executable then the user would not double click on it.

I've set this up on my (work) Windows computer so the Anaconda python.exe file opens any .py file I double click. Surely if you can do this on Windows you can do this on Linux?

Comment: Sure, but that strongly depends on the operating system ... https://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/

As I said, .py files shouldn't be executable by default, executable .py files should be executable, which is why that executable bit exists ...

Setting the interpreter to open py-files is a hack, which shouldn't be done. The only reason why this is the accepted way in windows is because windows doesn't offer an alternative.